# Onsubmit doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onsubmit

I have two forms and a button. Everything works fine in Firefox. I get a new window, with a Paypal payment, and in the window where everything happened i get the send_mail form submitted that will send an e-mail to the user. How can I make this work in Chrome? Why it's not working? I've tried anything (or so I think)!

So:

```
<form name="registerForm" id="registerForm" target="_blank" action="paypal_url" method="post" onsubmit="$('#send_mail').submit();">
...
</form>

<form name="send_mail" id="send_mail" action="" method="post">
...
</form>

<a onclick="$('#registerForm').submit()">Go to paypal and send confirmation mail</a>
```

Comment: `onsubmit` is not fired when using `submit()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a really good reason to use a javascript-only submit, why set up the form to be unusable if there is a javascript error?

Use a standard form input of type submit, give it an id, alter the look or text of the submit via javascript as necessary, and create onclick & onsubmit events as a layer on top of that functionality and have them return false.  Better fallbacks.

I'm not sure why you're trying to submit two forms at once, but how about this alternative (note that I haven't tested this code, but it should convey the idea):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#fallback-register-submit').hide(); // Hide the submit button.
$('#registration-link').show().click(function (){ // Show the link and attach the action.
    $('#registerForm').submit();
    return false; // Don't bother following the link anchor.
});
</script>

<form name="registerForm" id="registerForm" target="_blank" action="paypal_url" method="post""><!-- Single form that does all of the submitting. -->
...
...
<input type='submit' id='fallback-register-submit'>Register</input><!-- In the event of a javascript error for their browser, they can still buy your stuff! -->
<a id='registration-submit' style='display:none'>Go to paypal and send confirmation mail</a>
</form>
```

Comment: because one form is the paypal form, and the other is the thank you + update things on the database

Comment: Hmmm, well, if you can't merge the forms, certainly you could just add the additional submit to the code I posted, though that's not ideal.  The only other approach to that situation that I could think of is submitting your form before paypal's so that you're aware of the expectation that a user is going through your process and then having the paypal form be the final step in a multi-step form.  If that's not worth the trouble for you, or if it's not an amazingly important payment form, leaving one form or the other unsubmitted for javascript users may indeed be all that's practically left.

Answer (score 2):

why not just bind both submits to your a?

```
onclick="$('#send_mail').submit(); $('#registerForm').submit();"
```

if you want the other form to submit AFTER the first one:

```
onclick="$('#send_mail').submit( function() {$('#registerForm').submit();}); "
```

assuming you're using jquery here

Comment: first method submits only the #registerForm (opens paypal window, but doesn't submit #send_mail), and second does nothing..

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, you want to submit the form using a link?

Why not use "plain" javascript then? Without jQuery: `document.getElementById(....).submit()`

Or link the submit event to the link in a normal jQuery way:

`$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".yourLinkClass").click(function() { // or "#yourLinkId" for that matter
  $("#registerForm").submit();
 });
});`

And you also could use the submit button ;)

Comment: yes, that works fine, but it's not submitting the other form.. #send_mail

Comment: Well, if you want to submit two forms, i would suggest, for example, having them (or at least one of them) in different iframes. Or, and i think that it is a better variant, you collect all the necessary data in one form, pass it to the page that should open in the same window, and that page passes the data, that now is in your other form, to the page that you open in a _blank. Or, in the script that i suggested, you can probably add the corresponding line for the "_blank" form.