# The following JavaScript seems to be working in Firefox but not on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I'm new to web design/development; I have the following code to check if data is entered inside the text boxes. The JavaScript checks if data is added and comes up with a error if not entered?

This script works on FireFox but not on Google Chrome. The error messages don't appear and the data is added straight to the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
        function validate(){
            if(
            document.vulcanoForm.device_name.value == "" ||
            document.vulcanoForm.muid.value == "" ||
            document.vulcanoForm.map_version.value == "0.000")
            {
                alert("Please fill out all fields before clicking submit!");
                return false;  
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Hold on just adding to database :)");
                return true;  
            }
        }
    </script>

<body>
    <a href="index.xhtml"> Mogadishu </a> <br/>
    <form action="vulcanoprocess.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" name="vulcanoForm">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Device Information</legend>

            <label for="device_name">Device Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="device_name" id="device_name" /><br />

            <label for="muid">MUID:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="muid" id="muid" /><br />

            </form>
</body>
```

Comment: return false in the else, and try to print / alert the values and see the difference.

Comment: Just tried that but doesn't work unfortunately. Keeps adding the data into the database

Comment: works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/GeGpv/

Comment: @ZoltanToth  Just tried it on jsfiddle and worked for me too but just doesn't work on Google Chrome?

Comment: Do you have a submit button? This fiddle seems to work in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/PadMw/1/

Comment: @Prupel Yes it does have a submit button .. Yes it works with jsfiddle on Chrome but not when your entering data properly using a standard localhost url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug, use FireBug as a Firefox add on and select the javascript tab for errors or 'console'. Use that information to fix errors in code and when they go away test the script in chrome. If there are still errors, it might be because the chrome browser is missing some type of compatibility with js.

Comment: Hey didn't know what was causing the error when using firebug then found out that it was compatibility issues with javascript and chrome.

Thanks for the tip though

Comment: glad to be of help, if I was at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Onsubmit doesn't work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093431/onsubmit-doesnt-work-in-chrome)

lots to read when you google "google chrome onsubmit javascript"

edited to add

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){
        if(
        document.getElementById('device_name').value.trim() === "" ||
        document.getElementById('muid').value.trim() === "" ||
        document.getElementById('map_version').value.trim() === "0.000"
        )
        {
            alert("Please fill out all fields before clicking submit!");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Hold on just adding to database :)");
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>


    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.xhtml">Mogadishu</a><br>
    <form action="vulcanoprocess.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" name="vulcanoForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Device Information</legend> <label for="device_name">Device Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="device_name" id="device_name"><br>
            <label for="muid">MUID:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="muid" id="muid"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for that .. I'll read about it now .. Any suggestions for my code by any chance?

Comment: does the second alert appear?

Comment: It does work on Firefox but not on Chrome .. If the second alert doesn't appear it doesn't really matter

Comment: that suggests that there is an error in the js somewhere; perhaps because you have no map_version input. on my machine i changed your    document.vulcanoForm.device_name.value style lines to    document.getElementById('device_name').value.trim()  etcs and it worked in chrome.

Comment: When I pasted the code onto here I took map_version out when creating the form to shorten it but with that being there it doesn't work .. Is it possible for you to send me the edited code that's working on your Chrome?

Comment: I tried changing it but the same problem occurs just adds it straight to the database. Tried pasting the code but looks to complicated in such a small space

Comment: added the whole file to original post; is working in ff and chrome on my machine...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help works properly now! I really appreciate your help .. I'd add some rep points but my rep isn't high enough .. Thanks again!